# SQL Server 2014 upgraded - queries very slow

Tags: sql-server

We plan to upgrade production database from SQL Server 2008 to 2014. I already have two separate SQL Servers (2008 & 2014) running both Enterprise Edition.

These two servers have the same number of CPU cores (4) and Ram (32GB), and the SQL Server 2014 even has better CPU speed, but it is on the VMWare environment.

How did I migrate the database from 2008 to 2014 for testing? First, I backed up the database from 2008, then restored it on the 2014. After that, correct user accounts.... and make sure it is working fine.

Next, I ran all these commands suggested from different sites:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable "Print 'Rebuild index on: ?'; SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80);"
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print 'Reorganizing indexes for ?' ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REORGANIZE"
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='EXEC sp_recompile ''?'''
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN';
Change Compatibility To SQL Server 2014 (120)
```

Problem: I picked a query that takes around 10 secs on the old SQL Server 2008 and ran it on the SQL Server 2014, the same query is slower than old SQL Server 2008 twice -- it takes around 20 secs to finish. I checked the execution plan on both server and compared, the almost same values for the Cost %.

I am not sure what else to try. Please advise.

Thanks,

Comment: Assuming it's a view that is taking long: I recently did this myself, and found that `sp_refreshview viewname` was very needed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx

Comment: It is not a view, it is just a regular SELECT query.   Thanks!

Comment: Have you updated your statistics across your databases? Also: if you have a fresh restore on a new server, it might take a bit until the most frequently used pages are cached in memory - so right after the restore, your performance might be a bit less since almost all data retrieval has to go down to the disk and fetch pages

Comment: I have already tried the 'EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN';' but still not working. Not sure why, the same exact query, but just slow on SQL 2014.

Comment: Can you provide an execution plan from both servers? The old and the new one?

Comment: There is a new cardinality estimator in SQL Server 2014, which could be the reason -- and in that case the query plan should also be different.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Reasons could be:

1. There's a deadlock somewhere
2. The database's statistics and/or query plan cache are incorrect
3. The query is too complex and needs to be tuned

Deadlocks can be resolved by activity monitor

The second issue will cause the database to use a sub-optimal query plan. It can be resolved by clearing the statistics:
Try

```
exec sp_updatestats
```

If that doesn't work you could also try

```
dbcc freeproccache
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried both exec sp_updatestats and dbcc freeproccache, but still experience the same problem.  Any suggestion how to troubleshoot "deadlock somewhere"? and "plan cached incorrect?

Comment: I'm no expert with handling deadlock or using activity monitor, But can help you with a query, can you show the query ?

Comment: Is the data exactly same on both servers ?
Also can u make sure u have not used 'server name' some where in queries ?

Comment: Yes, the exact data on both services. I remote desktop to each server and ran the query locally from MS Management Studio.  In fact, I didn't believe that SQL Server 2014 is slower, so I have IT built me another VM server, same resource as the one with SQL 2014, then I loaded the SQL 2008, restored DB, then try the same query.  The same result in which SQL 2008 is faster and SQL 2004 is almost double the time.  thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

after you attach the database in sqlserver 2014, you should set the compatibility level to sql server 2008(100). databasename>right click>properties>options